# tomcat connection interrupted after a period of inactivity

Tags: spring, oracle, tomcat, jdbc, connection-pooling

I am developing an application with `spring` and hibernate `entityManager`

The oracle database is outside the DMZ, running on `tomcat 7` .

the connection will be interrupted after a period of inactivity by the firewall.

I added the ValidationQuery select 1 from dual in `context.xml` but it does not solve the problem.

```
2014-12-10 10:04:27 WARN  SqlExceptionHelper:143 - SQL Error: 17008, SQLState: null
2014-12-10 10:04:27 ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:144 - Connexion interrompue
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: JDBC exception on Hibernate data access: SQLException for SQL [n/a]; SQL state [null]; error code [17008]; Connexion interrompue; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Connexion interrompue
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:85)
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:132)
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
        at org.ooredoo.gprs.bean.LoginBean.access(LoginBean.java:78)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
        at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:273)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
        at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:101)
        at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:795)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1260)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:101)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateJdbcException: JDBC exception on Hibernate data access: SQLException for SQL [n/a]; SQL state [null]; error code [17008]; Connexion interrompue; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Connexion interrompue
```

database.properties:

`jdbc.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@**:1641:**
    jdbc.username=TSTXTL**EGIP
    jdbc.password=****
    jndi.dataSource=jdbc/dbds`

the applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">




    <context:component-scan base-package="**********" />
        <context:annotation-config/>

        <bean
            class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
            <property name="location">
                <value>classpath:database.properties</value>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="dataSource"
            class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy">
            <property name="targetDataSource">
                <bean class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
                    <property name="resourceRef">
                        <value>true</value>
                    </property>
                    <property name="jndiName">
                        <value>${jndi.dataSource}</value>
                    </property>




                </bean>
            </property>

        </bean>

        <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />


            <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
                <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                    <property name="showSql" value="true" />
                    <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
                    <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="jpaProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">none</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <!-- le gestionnaire de transactions -->
        <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
        <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
            <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        </bean>

        <!-- traduction des exceptions -->
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

        <!-- persistence -->
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    </beans>
```

Comment: it is possible you didn't close the connection before.
without knowing more about your setup / code you are running this is hard to say

Comment: Are you sure it is the firewall? It might just as well be the DBMS itself that is closing the connection after a period of inactivity.

Comment: You need to post the Hibernate database connectivity properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using `c3p0` conenction pool

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close" p:driverClass="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:jdbcUrl="${jdbc.url}" p:user="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}"
        p:preferredTestQuery="select 1 from dual" p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="300"
        p:maxStatements="100" p:acquireRetryAttempts="1" p:checkoutTimeout="1000"
        p:testConnectionOnCheckout="true" p:testConnectionOnCheckin="true"
        p:acquireIncrement="${c3p0.acquire_increment}" p:minPoolSize="${c3p0.min_size}"
        p:maxPoolSize="${c3p0.max_size}" p:maxIdleTime="${c3p0.max_idle_time}"

        p:unreturnedConnectionTimeout="${c3p0.unreturned_connection_timeout}" />
```

the DB.properties file:

```
#hibernate
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto= update
hibernate.connection.autocommit = true
hibernate.cache = true
hibernate.query.cache = true
hibernate.statistics = true
hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period=300
#c3p0 pool
c3p0.acquire_increment=5
c3p0.max_size=100
c3p0.min_size=5
c3p0.max_idle_time=1200
c3p0.unreturned_connection_timeout=120
```